# Error compiling GnuTLS on Centos 6.2

Tags: c, build, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to compile the latest GnuTLS on Centos 6.2.  I get this error message:

(this is only part)

```
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/gnutls.h... ok
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/gnutlsxx.h... ok
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/ocsp.h... ok
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/openpgp.h... ok
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/pkcs11.h... ok
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/pkcs12.h... ok
Creating documentation for ../lib/includes/gnutls/x509.h... ok
mv -f enums.texi-tmp enums.texi
make compare-makefile
make[5]: Entering directory `/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc'
ENUMS=`grep '^@c ' enums.texi | sed 's/@c //g' | sort`; \
    STR=""; \
    for i in $ENUMS; do \
        STR="$STR\nENUMS += enums/$i"; \
    done; \
    grep -v -e '^ENUMS += ' ./Makefile.am | \
        perl -p -e "s,^ENUMS =,ENUMS =$STR," > tmp-compare-makefile; \
    diff -u ./Makefile.am tmp-compare-makefile
rm -f tmp-compare-makefile
make[5]: Leaving directory `/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc'
mkdir enums
mkdir: cannot create directory `enums': File exists
make[4]: [stamp_enums] Error 1 (ignored)
./scripts/split-texi.pl enums enum < enums.texi
echo stamp_enums > stamp_enums
restore=: && backupdir=".am$$" && \
    am__cwd=`pwd` && CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && \
    rm -rf $backupdir && mkdir $backupdir && \
    if (/bin/sh /opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/build-aux/missing --run makeinfo --version) >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
      for f in gnutls.info gnutls.info-[0-9] gnutls.info-[0-9][0-9] gnutls.i[0-9] gnutls.i[0-9][0-9]; do \
        if test -f $f; then mv $f $backupdir; restore=mv; else :; fi; \
      done; \
    else :; fi && \
    cd "$am__cwd"; \
    if /bin/sh /opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/build-aux/missing --run makeinfo -I ../doc  -I . \
     -o gnutls.info gnutls.texi; \
    then \
      rc=0; \
      CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .; \
    else \
      rc=$?; \
      CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && \
      $restore $backupdir/* `echo "./gnutls.info" | sed 's|[^/]*$||'`; \
    fi; \
    rm -rf $backupdir; exit $rc
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-internals.texi:43: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_handshake' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-examples.texi:95: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_handshake' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1338: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_pk_bits_to_sec_param' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1336: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_sec_param_to_pk_bits' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1257: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_rnd' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1252: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_rnd' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1252: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hash_fast' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1251: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hash_get_len' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1250: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hash_deinit' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1249: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hash_output' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1248: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hash' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1247: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hash_init' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1247: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hmac_fast' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1246: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hmac_get_len' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1245: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hmac_deinit' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1244: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hmac_output' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1243: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hmac' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1242: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_hmac_init' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1233: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_tag' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1232: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_add_auth' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1231: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_deinit' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1230: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_set_iv' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1229: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_decrypt2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1228: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_encrypt2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1227: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_cipher_init' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1117: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_channel_binding' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1103: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_prf_raw' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1092: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_handshake' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1085: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_prf' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1077: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_set_params_function' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1074: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_rsa_params_export_pkcs1' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1073: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_rsa_params_import_pkcs1' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1072: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_set_rsa_export_params' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1071: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_rsa_params_generate2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1052: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_sec_param_to_pk_bits' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1049: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_anon_set_server_dh_params' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1048: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_set_dh_params' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1047: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dh_params_import_pkcs3' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1046: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dh_params_generate2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1043: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_anon_set_server_dh_params' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1042: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_set_dh_params' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1040: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dh_params_import_pkcs3' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1039: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dh_params_generate2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1026: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_resumption_requested' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1025: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_ticket_key_generate' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1024: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_ticket_enable_server' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1021: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_ticket_enable_server' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1019: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_ticket_key_generate' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1017: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_db_check_entry' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1019: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_db_set_remove_function' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1018: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_db_set_ptr' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1017: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_db_set_store_function' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1016: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_db_set_retrieve_function' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1012: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_db_check_entry' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1002: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_is_resumed' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:1000: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_ticket_enable_client' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:996: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_ticket_enable_client' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:990: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_set_data' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:989: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_get_id' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:988: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_get_data' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:985: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_session_set_data' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:748: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_priority_set' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:747: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_priority_set_direct' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:734: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_alert_get_name' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:733: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_error_to_alert' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:731: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_alert_send' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:729: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_alert_get' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:726: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_alert_send' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:725: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_recv' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:725: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_handshake' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:715: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_deinit' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:714: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_bye' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:711: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_deinit' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:707: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_bye' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:705: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_get_direction' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:704: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_check_pending' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:700: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_check_pending' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:697: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_check_pending' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:696: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_recv_seq' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:689: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_error_is_fatal' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:687: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_recv' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:685: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_send' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:680: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_error_is_fatal' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:674: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:669: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:668: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_certificate_set_verify_function' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:664: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_handshake' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:656: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_get_data_mtu' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:655: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_get_mtu' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:654: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_set_mtu' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:644: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_handshake' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:644: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_prestate_set' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:643: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_cookie_verify' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:642: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_cookie_send' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:641: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_key_generate' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:637: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_prestate_set' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:635: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_cookie_verify' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:633: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_dtls_cookie_send' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:623: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_init' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc//cha-gtls-app.texi:618: Cross reference to nonexistent node `gnutls_record_recv' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
Too many errors!  Gave up.
make[4]: *** [gnutls.info] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14/doc'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/tls/gnutls-3.0.14'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@Testserver gnutls-3.0.14]#
```

Is this Cross `reference to nonexistent node` means that this is a compilation error or I have wrong version of dependencies?

p.s I can build version 3.0.8 without problems! But versions higher that 3.0.8 can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from a texinfo file failing under makeinfo, not from C being compiled. I can't tell you why that is failing but it isn't a compilation error per se. texinfo is a documentation file format.

Comment: I wrote to GnuTLS mailing list. They told me that this is a well known bug and I can compile it without the documentation part.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed when install autogen(install with autoopts) from source:
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/autogen/
And then run the following command with a fresh source folder:

`./configure --disable-local-libopts --disable-libopts-install`